# How to manipulate text (HTML/CSS) without divs?

Tags: html, css

I want to create my Resume in HTML

Is the dimension of the page good as a A4?

How to Position the text like in picture, but I want without divs?

And How to make the page & the text fixed like a PDF or Word so when I print it, it be conform?

This is my Code:

```css
#name {
  font-size: 26pt;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}


/*ignore line break*/

.title {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.sous-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
  max-width: 44em;
  /*3ordh*/
  padding: 65 45px;
  margin: 6em auto 19em;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0.3em 1em rgb(110, 110, 110);
  height: 90em
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolionotabs.css">
  <title>Resume</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="name">REDACTED <br>REDACTED</p>
   REDACTED REDACTEDAdress Adress  EMailEMailEMail
 <br>   REDACTED0000000
  <hr />
  <p class="title">Objective</p>
  A highly motivated student looking for a first time position within a retail environment. Through my studies, i have demonstrated high levels of motivation, work ethic, and teamwork to achieve my predicted grades. I wish to utilise these skills to work
  with customers and satisfy their needs.
  <hr />
  <p class="title">Education</p>
  ISGS
  <p class="sous-title">IT management</p>
  September 2014 - July 2017<br> Graduated: No<br> Completed 2nd year
  <hr /> CSFMTS
  <p class="sous-title"></p>International trade</p>
  September 2019 - Current<br> Graduated: Yes<br> Currently on internship
  <hr />

  <p class="title">Work experience</p>
  <p class="sous-title"></p>REDACTED</p>
   REDACTED<br> October 2021 - November 2021<br>
  <hr />
  <p class="title">Languages</p>
  English •••••<br> French •••••<br> Italian •••••
  <hr />
  <p class="title">Skills</p>
  Problem-solving Reasonably experienced<br> Communication Reasonably experienced<br> Adaptability
  <br> Active Listening
  <hr />
  <p class="title">Technical skills</p>
  Ms-office Advanced level<br> Ciel 2019 Advanced level<br>
  <hr />
  <p class="title">Hobbies and interests</p>
  Exercising and healthcare<br> Yoga and meditation<br> Volunteering
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Off topic, but: If this isn't just a learning exercise and you plan on using this resume, using a technology you aren't confident with to build it might do more harm than good (And most job postings/recruiters won't accept HTML files or links to webpages)

Comment: Off topic aswell, but seems like your home address is in the code, might want to remove that so it's not visible here.

Comment: Can I ask the reason you don't want to use divs? To be able to **divide** this content with divs and nest the elements as you wish would be made very minimal if you used divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#name{
    font-size: 26pt;
    font-family: garamond;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:inline;
 } /*ignore line break*/
 
.title{font-size: 12pt;}
.sous-title{font-weight: bold;}

body{
   padding: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    max-width: 44em; /*3ordh*/
    padding: 65 45px;
    margin: 6em auto 19em;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0.3em 1em rgb(110, 110, 110);
    height: 90em
}

.fright{
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolionotabs.css">
    <title>Resume</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="name">REDACTED <br>REDACTED</p>
    
    <span class="fright">
      REDACTED<br>
      REDACTED
    </span>
    <span class="fright">
      REDACTED<br>
      REDACTED
     </span>
     
    <hr />
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="230px">Objective</td>
        <td>
        A highly motivated student looking for a first time position within a retail environment. Through my studies, i have demonstrated high levels of motivation, work ethic, and teamwork to achieve my predicted grades. I wish to utilise these skills to work with customers and satisfy their needs.
        </td>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">Education</td>
        <td>
            ISGS<br>
            <b>IT management</b><br>
            September 2014 - July 2017<br>
            Graduated: No<br>
            Completed 2nd year
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          CSFMTS<br>
         <b> International trade</b><br>
          September 2019 - Current<br>
          Graduated: Yes<br>
          Currently on internship
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Work experience</td>
        <td>
          <b>REDACTED</b><br>
          REDACTED<br>
          October 2021 - November 2021<br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Languages</td>
        <td>
          English •••••<br>
          French •••••<br>
          Italian •••••
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Skills</td>
        <td>
          Problem-solving Reasonably experienced<br>
          Communication Reasonably experienced<br>
          Adaptability<br>
          Active Listening
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Technical skills</td>
        <td>
          Ms-office Advanced level<br>
          Ciel 2019 Advanced level<br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hobbies and interests</td>
        <td>
            Exercising and healthcare<br>
            Yoga and meditation<br>
            Volunteering
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually i have a version with tables and found it more difficult than divs. 
This explanation was very good, i'll try to solve it in both ways divs and tables, thank y'all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I can answer two of your questions.

> How to Position the text like in picture, but i want without divs..?

Divs are really not too difficult and a core concept of html, so it would be beneficial to learn how to use them. You can find some good explanation on [MDN Web Docs div details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) to help you. But since you ask for an alternate, I can offer one: Tables. Now, I personally do not like to use tables, but it can do the job. A warning is that tables can make it more difficult to have a responsive site that works well on small screens. But since you wish to mimic a printed document it would work for that.

Example:

```html
<hr />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="title">Objective</p>
    </td>
    <td>A highly motivated student looking for a first time position within a retail environment. Through my studies, i have demonstrated high levels of motivation, work ethic, and teamwork to achieve my predicted grades. I wish to utilise these skills to
      work with customers and satisfy their needs.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
```

That's a bit basic and doesn't match the style you want, but gives you the idea of how to place the two columns side by side. Of course you will need to add the appropriate properties to set the cell sizes, padding, and spacing to what you want it to be.

The basic principle is use `<tr>` for each row and `<td>` for each cell in the row. Then build like you would a spreadsheet or table in a word document.

> And how to make the page and the text fixed like a pdf or word so when i print it, it be conform?

If you use tables, you can use a fixed width (in pixels). That can accomplish this. A good reference is [Fixed-width tables with text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#fixed-width_tables_with_text-overflow) on MDN. But again, a warning. This approach can cause difficulty on smaller screens; it is not a responsive design.

Edit: In the other answer, the user updated your entire code into tables for you. But to make it always print the same you may need to add fixed widths. I do hope my answer explains to you way tables are an option and the possible issue with them.